# Problems with query using foreign key sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I own this model.

```
'use strict'

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = require('../../config/database');

const TransactionModel = db.define('transactions', {
    id : {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    guid: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
});

module.exports = TransactionModel
```

I own this second model

```
'use strict'

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var db = require('../../config/database');
const transactionModel = require('../models/transactionModel')


const accessCredentialsApiModel = db.define('transactions_items', {
    guid: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    transaction_id : {
        field : 'transaction_id',
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: 'transactions',
        key: 'id'
    },
    created_at : {
        type : Sequelize.DATE
    },
    updated_at : {
        type : Sequelize.DATE
    },
    qtd_event : {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    amount: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2)
    }

});

transactionModel.hasMany(accessCredentialsApiModel);


module.exports = accessCredentialsApiModel
```

I am using association for a foreign key relation by placing the foreign key in the second model. But it's time to make a query like the one below.

```
   let transactions = await transactionModel.findAll({
        where: {
          entity_id: arrayEntities[i].id,
        },
        include: [
            { model: transactionsItemsModel}
        ],
        raw: true
    });
    console.log(transactions)
```

I have the error message

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'transactions_items.transactionId' in 'field list'
```

I can not find a solution to the problem, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that its looking for `transactionId` but what you have defined is `transaction_id`. You can tell sequelize what should be the foreign key and the source key like this

```
transactionModel.hasMany(accessCredentialsApiModel, {foreignKey: 'id', sourceKey: 'transaction_id'});
```